# Can a MSVC class have a deletion destructor without a vftable?

Tags: c++, hexrays, msvc, virtual-functions

I'm reversing the following smart pointee-like MSVC `class Buffer : public Referencable` with IDA / Hexrays:

```
struct Referencable
{
    int m_refs;
};
struct Buffer : Referencable
{
    void* m_pData;
};
```

This class apparently has no vftable, which I deduce from its (base) constructor not storing any vftable-like structure:

```
Buffer *__thiscall Buffer::ctor(Buffer *this)
{
    Referencable::ctor(this);
    this->m_pData = NULL;
    return this;
}
Referencable *__thiscall Referencable::ctor(Referencable *this)
{
    // <-- no vftable assignment here or anywhere -->
    this->m_refs = 0;
    return this;
}
```

When this object is being deleted, I see the following method:

```
Buffer *__thiscall Buffer::ddtor(Buffer *this, char flags)
{
    Buffer::dtor(this);
    if ( (flags & 1) != 0 )
        operator delete(this);
    return this;
}
void __thiscall Buffer::dtor(Buffer *this)
{
    free(this->m_pData);
    Referencable::dtor(this);
}
void __thiscall Referencable::dtor(Referencable *this)
{
    ; // nop
}
```

<sup>(I can assure that this is indeed the deletion method belonging to this class due to how the capturing smart pointer calls it)</sup>

According to igorsk's [Reversing Microsoft Visual C++ Part II: Classes, Methods and RTTI](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) article, `Buffer::ddtor` seems to be a deletion destructor, which however are only available to classes with *virtual destructors*:

> 6. Deleting Destructors
>
> **When class has a virtual destructor, compiler generates a helper function - deleting destructor**. Its purpose is to make sure that a proper _operator delete_ gets called when destructing a class. Pseudo-code for a deleting destructor looks like following:
>
> ```
> virtual void * A::'scalar deleting destructor'(uint flags)
> {
>   this->~A();
>   if (flags&1) A::operator delete(this);
> };
> ```

Thus my class seems to contradict another statement in that article, mentioning a virtual deletion destructor call which does not exist in my assembly (the deletion destructor above is called directly by the smart pointer logic):

> If A's destructor is virtual, it's invoked virtually:
>
> ```
> mov ecx, pA
> push 3
> mov eax, [ecx] ;fetch vtable pointer      // <-- what vftable? I have none!
> call [eax]     ;call deleting destructor
> ```

Now I am a little confused.

- Does this class have a virtual destructor now or not?
- Is it possible for a deletion destructor to be generated even if I do not have a virtual destructor, and what are the requirements?
- Or is this what is *always* generated when I call `delete` on *anything* and I simply misunderstood the article?
- If it helps clearing my confusion, what is the exact difference between a deletion destructor and virtual destructor anyway?

On a postscriptum note I know this assembly quite well otherwise and never noticed *any* kind of code optimizations (lucky me); I wonder how a vftable could've been optimized out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was confused over the articles wording due to initially seeing deletion destructors as virtual destructors. I analyzed a small scratchpad program and realized the following:

- Deletion destructors (in PDBs referred to as "scalar deleting destructor") are generated whenever I call `delete` on an object with a destructor, **no matter if it is virtual or not**. It's practically there to ensure to call the user destructor code and then actually free the memory.
- Only as soon as I make the destructor virtual (or declare another method virtual), MSVC *always* generates a vftable (what else?).

There are probably exceptions to these observations but so far I haven't seen them. Feel free to expand my knowledge here!